# How do I make Ubuntu start fbterm in the tty on startup?

Tags: terminal, console, ubuntu-12.04, tty

When I was testing openSUSE about a week ago, I noticed that tty1 (yes, just tty1) had the openSUSE background. I want to do the same in Ubuntu.

I found a way using fbsplash. I'm not too keen on that since it involves modifying the kernel.

Then I found fbterm, which allows you to use your own background and it doesn't involve modifying the kernel.

So I got fbterm working; I set it up and now I can run it as myself (not as root) and it works just fine.

Now all I need is how to make it start in the tty when I start Ubuntu.

Edit: It also needs to act something like getty when I start it up; otherwise I won't be able to log in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you'll need to edit your inittab file. On Debian, it's located in `/etc/inittab`, and I would guess it might be somewhere similar on Ubuntu. The normal TTY prompt is managed with a program called `getty`, so you'll need to scroll down to where that program is set up. You should see a lot of lines similar to this:

```
# Note that on most Debian systems tty7 is used by the X Window System,
# so if you want to add more getty's go ahead but skip tty7 if you run X.
#
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
2:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty2
3:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty3
4:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty4
5:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty5
6:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty6
```

Next, we'll need a program called `rungetty`. This allows you to run programs on a TTY as a particular user. `fbterm` requires you to be root to access the framebuffer, by the by. So you could run `fbterm` on TTY2 like so (double dashes signify the end of switches for `rungetty`):

```
2:23:respawn:/sbin/rungetty -u root tty2 -- fbterm
```

Only one problem; you have a beautiful framebuffer-based terminal, but you're logged in as root! Having an unauthenticated root prompt is about as bad for security as it gets. That won't do.

We can use a program called `login` to get around this by accepting another set of user credentials, and then starting bash or zsh or whatever your login shell happens to be. Luckily, `fbterm` can accept a command as its final argument (again, double dashes prevent `fbterm` and `rungetty` from getting arguments mixed up:

```
2:23:respawn:/sbin/rungetty -u root tty2 -- fbterm -- login
```

With that, you should have `fbterm` running on one of your TTYs.

Comment: How about in a system where the "rungetty" utility is not available? Is there another method to accomplish the same?

Comment: @dtmland It looks like agetty and mingetty have options ( -l and --login‐prog respectively) that may be helpful, but I haven't tried them myself. You can also try pulling the rungetty sources from the debian package archive and building on your system.

Comment: By the way, I'm having trouble with fbterm in general - perhaps your expertise could come in handy? http://superuser.com/questions/892028/fbterm-expected-behavior-at-launch

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change the tty terminal by editing:

```
/etc/init/tty1.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I thought it deserved a better answer rather than one that was copy pasted and doesn't apply to modern Ubuntu (22.04 at time of writing).

Start by creating a new script using the following command:

```shell
$ sudoedit /usr/sbin/fbterm-login
```

Enter the following as its contents, then save and exit.

```shell
#!/usr/bin/sh
fbterm -- /usr/bin/sh -c "TERM=fbterm login -p"
```

Then mark the script as executable with:

```shell
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/fbterm-login
```

This script starts `fbterm` with the correct arguments to launch the login program. It will also set the `TERM` environment variable to `fbterm` which will enable 256 color support.

Next, edit the getty service file by calling:

```shell
$ sudoedit /usr/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service
```

Find the following line:

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' --noclear %I $TERM
```

Comment it out and add the following line after it:

```shell
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear -n -l /usr/sbin/fbterm-login %I $TERM
```

Then save and exit the editor.

Now restart and enjoy using `fbterm` as your virtual terminal.

As an additional note, I've noticed that `fbterm` doesn't allow you to switch between vts using Ctrl+Alt+F[1-9], but it *does* allow you move to other vts using Alt+LeftArrow and Alt+RightArrow.